# regular expression's $ character

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression

I know when I use `$`, it means characters before `$` must be shown at the end of the string.

But, I don't know difference between the tests given below, when the variable `a` is integer:

1. `[[ a =~ -?[0-9]+ ]]`
2. `[[ a =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]`

Are they same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the expressions `[0-9]+` and `[0-9]+$` are not the same.  The first will match one or more numeral *at any position* in the string, and the latter will *only* match a series of one or more numerals at the *end* of the string.  To demonstrate, I will use this script which tests your expressions against its first parameter:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$1

if [[ $a =~ -?[0-9]+ ]]; then
   echo "match to first expression"
else
   echo "no match to first expression"
fi

if [[ $a =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]; then
   echo "match to second expression"
else
   echo "no match to second expression"
fi
```

The results are as follows:

```
$ ./test.sh 12345
match to first expression
match to second expression
$ ./test.sh 12345AA
match to first expression
no match to second expression
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, number 2 should be modified to `[[ a =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]` .  I mean, I assume when the variable `a` is integer. So, `a` only has integer value. Still, different result? If it has different result, can you give me an example??

Comment: I have expanded upon this in the updated answer.

Comment: @A.Cho If you're assuming `a` is an integer, what's the point of the test?

Comment: I think the question was more about what the use-case of the `$` anchor is, @muru (:

Comment: @DopeGhoti I got that. My question is: Does the OP know the point of the test as written? They didn't come up with it out of thin air, did they?

Answer (score 3):

No; both expressions are different.

`[[ a =~ -?[0-9]+ ]]` will test whether a contains an integer at any location. It can be anywhere in the string; it doesn't matter.

but

On the other hand, `[[ a =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]` will test whether a is comprised exclusively of integers (with an optional - as the first character), because ^ is for the start of the tested string, and $ marks end of the string.

This means that in the second expression any non-numerals anywhere in the string will not match.